# Modify core/image block by adding inner span to figcaption in save

Tags: block-editor

I'd need to slightly modify the structure of the `core/image` `figcaption` component in the filtered `save` function by adding a `span` wrapper to the contents of the caption (I need another markup element for my frontend plans). I have worked a lot with the editor and done a lot of custom blocks, but I have struggled on exactly this task a couple of times. I believe it's some misconception of mine with React (as always). Everything works and I can `console.log` all values at all stages successfully until the very moment when I try to re-inject my new JSX into `props.children`. As soon as I uncomment this line I get a blank screen and React tells me `Type error: children.props is undefined`.

This is my code for the filtered `save` function of the extended `core/image` block:

```
function customImageSave( element, blockType, attributes ) {

if ( ! restrictToBlocks.includes( blockType.name ) ) {
    return element;
}
// Custom boolean attribute added to core image block
const { addSpan } = attributes;

const { children } = element.props;
// array with img and figcaption elements (maybe good idea to spread in new array?)
const innerElems = [ ...children.props.children ];
// image
const theImage = innerElems[0];
// figcaption
const theCaption = innerElems[1];
// only if figcaption is used at all (otherwise 'false')
if ( theCaption ) {
    // get string value of figcaption content
    let theValue = theCaption.props.value;
    let theJSX;
    // only if span needs to be added
    if ( addSpan ) {
        // check if figcaption is already wrapped in <span></span>
        if ( ! theValue.includes( '<span>' ) ) {
            // otherwise construct new JSX
            theJSX = <figcaption><span>{theValue}</span></figcaption>;
        }
    } else {
        // if no span should be added but figcaption already includes <span> wrapper, remove it
        if ( theValue.includes( '<span>' ) ) {
            theValue.replace( '<span>', '' );
            theValue.replace( '</span>', '' );
            // rebuild 'original' JSX without <span>
            theJSX = <figcaption>{theValue}</figcaption>;
        }
    }
    // new Array with unchanged img element and new figcaption element
    const newChildren = [ theImage, theJSX ];
    // try to inject it (fails)
    element.props.children.props.children = newChildren;
    return element;
}

return element;
}
addFilter( 'blocks.getSaveElement', 'vortac/custom-image-save', customImageSave );
```

Any help / advise really appreciated. Would it be better to post the whole code of the block (to test it?)

Comment: you should not be modifying props like that, even more soo modifying children, props are unchanged, immutable, this is very bad practice and a dead end for what you're trying to achieve. Even if it worked, it would  break block validation.  Instead, ask how to solve your problem, not how to fix your solution. Why do you need an inner span? What are you trying to do that requires it

Comment: I haven't re-evaluated this in some time, so my knowledge might be outdated: It used to be extremely difficult to modify core blocks - even with the `getSaveElement` and other filters. So I often went to create custom blocks and disable the core ones ..

Comment: I thought about using a custom block as well as conditionally changing the structure when the block is rendered on the frontend (using PHP, render_blocks), but the former seemed overdoing it because I only needed a minimal adaption whereas the latter feels hacky because of mingling with the html string in inner_html. My goal is to have a simple card type image that flips to the name of the person on a single colored background on hover and I thought it would be smart to simply use the figcaption for that (and not to use a completely new custom construct).

Comment: And I need to (CSS) animate/transition the hover background and the text separately, therefore pseudo-elements can't be used on figcaption.

Comment: @TomJNowell I have succesfully added elements to props/children in the past (even for the image block as well as other core blocks). As an example, I have conditionally added a div with credits to image blocks. This has worked in similar fashion in the filtered core block's save function, it worked and did not break anything (like block validation). Is this also considered bad practice? How would this be accomplished then in React generally or the Block Editor specifically?

Comment: it would be easier to do this on render in php via the block filters, or in javascript on the browser. You should never modify props directly in react, that's what state and context are for. React is built around the assumption that if you give a component the same props you will get the same result, with state covering local changes. That's how it knows when to re-render or if changes are made

Comment: Thanks Tom, really appreciate your help. Seems like I need to get my head around these concepts better. I think I'll give render_block another try. But just for clarification: if I read this paragraph from the docs https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#blocks-getsaveelement what is meant with [...] to modify the element's props or replace its children, or [...]. Isn't this exactly what I am trying to do?